# Combine results of two SQL queries in one but keep separeted form

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to combine two result in one query but keep the separeted columns

I have two SQL query result:

```
A-query result   B-query result

a1                    b1
a2                    b2
a3                    b3
a4                    b4
```

I want to combine these two result in one query but keep the separeted columns
(it could be a question why i want to this but that is not the point now):

```
|A-query result  | B-query result|
|a1              | b1            |
|a2              | b2            |
|a3              | b3            |
|a4              | b4            |
```

If i use these, the results are always the same:

```
SELECT a.a1,b.b1 FROM
(SELECT teams.name AS a1 FROM teams JOIN matches ON teams.id=matches.home_team_id WHERE matches.home_team_id=3 OR matches.away_team_id=3) AS a,
(SELECT teams.name AS b1 FROM teams JOIN matches ON teams.id=matches.away_team_id WHERE matches.home_team_id=3 OR matches.away_team_id=3) AS b

SELECT ho.h,aw.a FROM
(SELECT teams.name AS h FROM teams JOIN matches ON teams.id=matches.home_team_id WHERE matches.home_team_id=3 OR matches.away_team_id=3) AS ho
INNER JOIN
(SELECT teams.name AS a FROM teams JOIN matches ON teams.id=matches.away_team_id WHERE matches.home_team_id=3 OR matches.away_team_id=3) AS aw
```

i get:

```
 A      B
|a1   |b1  |
|a2   |b1  |
|a3   |b1  |
|a4   |b1  |
|a1   |b2  |
|a2   |b2  |
|a3   |b2  |
|a4   |b2  | etc..
```

How could i get that form that i want?

Comment: I have no idea what your sample query has to do with your question.

Comment: How are the rows from two queries related to each other? Does a1 correspond to b1 just because both are first rows?

Comment: Do they always have the same number of rows?

Comment: perhaps ifyou could set up a small SQL fiddle we could be more helpful. Or post some more data on the tables involved in the query.

Comment: See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) , like everybody else i have no idea what you mean here.

Comment: What  are the actual (working as single query) queries that need to be combined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` and `join`:

```
select a.result, b.result
from (select a.*, row_number() over (order by ?) as seqnum
      from <a>
     ) a join
     (select b.*, row_number() over (order by ?) as seqnum
      from <b>
     ) b
     on a.seqnum = b.seqnum
order by a.seqnum;
```

The `?` is for the ordering of each of the result sets.  `<a>` and `<b>` are for whatever query you are using.

Comment: Note @labianconera be sure for *"whatever query you are using."* that the orders are **not** non deterministic ("random"), meaning sorting with atleast one column in the `ORDER BY` clause which has a `PRIMARY` or `UNIQUE` key to make it deterministic (fixed) on every run otherwise you risk joining "randomly" unrelated data with this query..

Comment: Thank you all for help,  row_number() and join solution fit well as a1 and b1 correspond to each other. Thanks for this great idea it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Since not much information is given you could try something like the following, although i am not sure what are the two queries that you want joined results.

```
SELECT a.a1,b.b1 FROM
(SELECT teams.name AS a1, teams.id AS a2 FROM teams JOIN matches ON teams.id=matches.home_team_id) AS a,
(SELECT teams.name AS b1, teams.id AS b2 FROM teams JOIN matches ON teams.id=matches.away_team_id) AS b 
WHERE a.a2 <> b.b2
GROUP BY a.a2,b.b2;
```

Which produces this output.

```
a1  a2
a1  a3
a1  a4
a1  b1
a1  b2
a1  b3
a1  b4
a2  a1
a2  a3
a2  a4
a2  b1
a2  b2
a2  b3
a2  b4
a3  a1
a3  a2
a3  a4
a3  b1
a3  b2
a3  b3
a3  b4
a4  a1
a4  a2
a4  a3
a4  b1
a4  b2
a4  b3
a4  b4
b1  a1
b1  a2
b1  a3
b1  a4
b1  b2
b1  b3
b1  b4
b2  a1
b2  a2
b2  a3
b2  a4
b2  b1
b2  b3
b2  b4
b3  a1
b3  a2
b3  a3
b3  a4
b3  b1
b3  b2
b3  b4
b4  a1
b4  a2
b4  a3
b4  a4
b4  b1
b4  b2
b4  b3
```

There is a working [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b14e9e0/14) to check and test;

Comment: You have a good line of defense when getting substantial criticism based on information which we don't know.but no i have nothing to try it on..  Anyhow i removed mine comment.. But still `WHERE` and `HAVING` does not ("always") results into the same results or mean the same thing in the SQL language or SQL dialects for that matter ..

Comment: @RaymondNijland not much data on what you are trying to do ...

Comment: *"not much data on what you are trying to do"* note that i am not the topicstarter ...

Comment: @RaymondNijland :) sorry mate you are correct... on both issues.

Comment: right about what ? that i am not the topicstarter or you used HAVING wrong ? :-)

Comment: @RaymondNijland i still can't understand what result-set the OP i trying to get. What  are the queries that need to be combined?

Comment: Now thats the one million question right there, if i knew i would already had posted a answer meself